# Guava CacheBuilder not working as expected

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

Hi I am new to google guava collections so I need collection which will expire some time period.So I have write following code but it is not removing data after expire time.Can anyone tell me what is the issue of code.

```
Cache<String, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterAccess(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        Object object = new Object();            
        cache.put(object.getId(), object);
        System.out.println("size :" + cache.size());
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        System.out.println("After Size :" + cache.size());
```

I need to add objects to map and after expire time period it will remove from map.But above code after and before thread contains object in map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadoc of [`expireAfterAccess`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) states:

> Expired entries may be counted in `Cache.size()`, but will never be visible to read or write operations. Expired entries are cleaned up as part of the routine maintenance described in the class javadoc.

That means that even though the entries are counted with `.size()`, they won't be visible on any other operation.

These invalid entries will be removed automatically. According to the javadoc, this happens at the following situations:

- **The entry is accessed using get:** 
  The map sees the entry is outdated and removes it directly.
- **On occasional cache accesses:** 
  Sometimes accessing the `.get()` method will trigger the internal cleanup, the javadoc doesn't define any period for this.
- **Manual calls to [`Cache.cleanUp()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#cleanUp--)**:
  This trigger the cleanup routine directly and removes all outdated entries.

More information seems to be explained in the [Github Wiki of the cache class](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#user-content-when-does-cleanup-happen).

If you want to be notices when an entry is removed, you can use a [RemovalListener](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener.html). You can set this listener on the cachebuilder using [`.removalListener(...)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#removalListener-com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener-).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.And one thing i want to know how to read value from cache  map and write Cache map .Is it the same way we do in standard java map.

Comment: When i add cache.getIfPresent("123") before thred sleep it will return null value.And "123" is the key for object i have added.

Comment: sorry buddy it is my mistake.Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Reply to comment 1:**  Using standard operations like `.get()` and `.put()` works using the cache, but building the `Cache` using [`build(CacheLoader)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#build\(com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader\)) is more powerful because `LoadingCache` will automatically create the value in the cache if it doesn't exists. **Reply to comment 2:**  2 milliseconds is a very short timeout and the internal code may timeout before the getting code is called **Reply to comment 3:** No problem everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: Thanks that is the mistake i have done.And in above is object completely remove from memory or is still in memory.If it is not accessible but it is in memory how to remove object from memory.

Comment: Added information for removal to the post. Cache manages it automatically, but you can also call `.cleanUp()`